# Unable to update current job in Careers 2.0

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs, cv

I am not able to update current employment status. There does not seems to be any link provided to edit that field:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the problem (blanking out personal information if you'd like)?

Comment: Please see the answer below, and sorry for the difficulty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scroll down to **Experience** and edit or add entries there. Any time span that includes *Current* will be displayed up in the header unless you click the opt-out button.

Comment: This is correct.